# Is there any way to find out two mouse pointers in a browser? Like If I am using any desk app then there will be two mouse pointer

Tags: browser, mouseevent

The idea here is to know using pointer position or anything to definitely know If two pointers are there in a browser window.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way of doing that because anydesk simulates the existence of two cursors pretty much. the OS itself doesn't support that and the browser/page will never truly work with two cursors as well afaik.
to test this out, check a simple "hover"-effect with two cursors at the same time. this should not work as well.
only thing i can think of: you could set a variable if the hovering starts (like a counter) and subtract from it when it stops, so that you can check on "2". but i wouldn't really bet on that working all the time.

may i ask what the goal behind this is, because maybe there's a work-around for that.